# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error message XNA 4.0 c#

Tags: c#, object, reference, instance

```
for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < attributes[i].Count; j++)
            {
                switch (attributes[i][j])
                {
                    case "Image":
                        images.Add(this.content.Load<Texture2D>(contents[i][j]));
                        fade.Add(new FadeAnimation());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the following error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at the line:

`for (int j = 0; j < attributes[i].Count; j++)`

Any ideas?

Comment: attributes[i] is null

Comment: Or more correct, attributes[i] is null.

Comment: @Jonesy Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen, sorry, that was what I ment haha

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the value at the index `i` is `null`. You could protect this code like this:

```
if (attributes[i] != null)
{
    for (...)
}
```

At least that's one way. There are probably many other ways of protecting it. That's your call.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(attributes!=null)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < attributes[i].Count; j++)
        {
            switch (attributes[i][j])
            {
                case "Image":
                    images.Add(this.content.Load<Texture2D>(contents[i][j]));
                    fade.Add(new FadeAnimation());
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

}
```